# Getting Problem whlie deploying my nodejs server in heruku

Tags: node.js, git, express, github, heroku

i am building a crud application where in frontend i have used react and in backend i have used nodejs with express. When i try to push my app.js into heroku, i am getting this error.
I have tried so many ways i found in the internet. But still i am getting same error.

```
git push heroku master
Enumerating objects: 1235, done.
Counting objects: 100% (1235/1235), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (1187/1187), done.
Writing objects: 100% (1235/1235), 2.19 MiB | 949.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 1235 (delta 120), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
remote: -----> Determining which buildpack to use for this app
remote: -----> Node.js app detected
remote: 
remote: -----> Build failed
remote:  !     Two different lockfiles found: package-lock.json and yarn.lock
remote: 
remote:        Both npm and yarn have created lockfiles for this application,
remote:        but only one can be used to install dependencies. Installing
remote:        dependencies using the wrong package manager can result in missing
remote:        packages or subtle bugs in production.
remote: 
remote:        - To use npm to install your application's dependencies please delete
remote:          the yarn.lock file.
remote: 
remote:          $ git rm yarn.lock
remote: 
remote:        - To use yarn to install your application's dependences please delete
remote:          the package-lock.json file.
remote: 
remote:          $ git rm package-lock.json
remote:     
remote:        https://help.heroku.com/0KU2EM53
remote: 
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote:  !
remote:  ! ## Warning - The same version of this code has already been built: 6f7f0c809a340fce866cad56f94827ead03983b4
remote:  !
remote:  ! We have detected that you have triggered a build from source code with version 6f7f0c809a340fce866cad56f94827ead03983b4
remote:  ! at least twice. One common cause of this behavior is attempting to deploy code from a different branch.
remote:  !
remote:  ! If you are developing on a branch and deploying via git you must run:
remote:  !
remote:  !     git push heroku <branchname>:main
remote:  !
remote:  ! This article goes into details on the behavior:
remote:  !   https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/duplicate-build-version
remote: 
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !       Push rejected to mern-crud-in.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/mern-crud-in.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/mern-crud-in.git'
```

Comment: back up from the heroku push.  locally , cycle thru a complete rebuild : 1. delete both the lock files mentioned in the error 2. rm  node_module/* 3. rebuild 4. retest 5. retry the push heroku master

Comment: tried. still getting same problem.

Comment: It looks like you used both `yarn` and `npm` to build your project and you must only use one of them.